# Keyboard/Space Bar misbehavior for UITextField with custom character input

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard, first-responder

This is really bizarre and I've already wasted almost an entire day trying to figure out this ridiculous little problem... ahhh, I need some help from any who are willing to dig into this :(

So I've got a UITextField, in which I need to limit the input characters to lowercase alpha, numeric and underscores only.  No spaces, but still allow backspace/delete.  This is all working fine with the code below :

```
'#define ALPHAStr @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
'#define NUMERICStr @"0123456789_"
```

Create the NSCharacterSet:

```
_charactersStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ALPHAStr,NUMERICStr];
_allowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:_charactersStr];
```

implement restrictions for UITextField Entry:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField == self.entryTxtField){ 

        if (string.length == 0 && range.length > 0) {  /*this is to allow backspace*/
            return YES;
        }
        else {  /*this limits the input to only allowed characters*/
            return ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:_allowedCharacters].location != NSNotFound);
        }
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

So this at first glance seems to work great...  but I noticed an incredibly strange issue, and I'm not sure if it's a bug in iOS 6...

Space Bar is disabled with this code, and at first it works fine, touching the space bar shows the key shadowing and makes the click sound, but it does not input a space into the UITextField (correct behavior).  However, (it is random, but this is one way I have found that will eventually trigger it...) if you type 3 letters fast, then hit space bar a few times fast... then 3 more letters fast, then space bar a few times, and continue this, the problems start. example:  type "abc (space)(space)(space) xyz (space)(space)(space) gbh(space)(space)(space)"

Now EVERY OTHER space bar touch will act as though you are touching one of the bottom keys just above it (usually v, b or n).  So instead of showing the pressed darkening of the space bar (to let you know you pressed the space bar) it actually is darkening one of these other keys and entering v,b or n into the text field.  But it is only happening every other space bar tap, and it only happens after the above mentioned sequence (or some other random combination of letters and space bar attempts).

This is a really strange problem, and I think I have done my best to try to explain it here.  ANY help at all here would be greatly appreciated.  And if something wasn't explained clearly by me, I would be happy to make an attempt at clarifying.  Thanks

Comment: Most likely you are actually tapping one of the keys above the spacebar. I do this all of the time when trying to quickly type a message on my iPhone. Your big fat thumb only needs to be off by a pixel to get the letter instead of the spacebar.

Comment: @rmaddy I wish this were so.  lol I wouldn't have wasted 7 hours trying to figure out the problem & then come here on SO if there were any chance what so ever it was just me incorrectly touching the keypad.  But thanks for the comment

Comment: I had a similar problem. It seems to be related to when NO is returned by the function.